# Call to undefined function mysql_rum_rows() - Error in Login Form PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this error when I try to login in to my PHP form:

Call to undefined function mysql_rum_rows()

This is my code

```html
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("login");

    if(isset($_POST['inloggen'])) {
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

      $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '". $username . "' AND '" . $password . "'";

      $result = mysql_query($query);

      if(mysql_rum_rows($result) == 1) {
        echo "Juiste gegevens!";
      }
        else {
          echo "Onjuiste gegevens!";
        }

      echo "<br />";
    }

?>

<form method="post" action="">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password"/><br />

  <input type="submit" name="inloggen" value="Inloggen"/>

</form>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this ? I'm a noob to PHP and I've got this from a book called "PHP en MySQL" So I don't know why it isn't working

Comment: it should be `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: please read and learn - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: I recommend buying a new book, `mysql_` functions are removed in PHP 7.

Comment: Please avoid the use of `mysql_` functions since they are deprecated and removed in PHP 7, use PDO or MySQLi instead

Comment: typos are off topic. and use mysqli_* function or PDO instead.

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Typo error. Need to write `mysqli_num_rows`

Also No need to check `mysqli_num_rows()`.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
// $result will give you boolean TRUE or FALSE
    if ($result) {
        echo "Juiste gegevens!";
    } else {
        echo "Onjuiste gegevens!";
    }
```

**Suggestions**:-

1) You need to encrypt your password before save to Database. One of the simple encryption techniques is `md5`. and you can check password with DB by below way.

```
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
```

2) You can write your query as below:-

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND '$password'";
```

3) Always check for query errors. You should use `mysql_error()` to get query error.

**Warning:-**

> mysql_* was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

U misstyped mysql_num_rows (mysql_rum_rows), i guess thats all about it.
Good luck.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");

if (isset($_POST['inloggen'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND '" . $password . "'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        echo "Juiste gegevens!";
    } else {
        echo "Onjuiste gegevens!";
    }

    echo "<br />";
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br />

    <input type="submit" name="inloggen" value="Inloggen"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, use **mysql_num_rows** instead *mysql_rum_rows*